# Parsing specific words and appending them inside a data-attribute

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is there a way I can parse specific words and then turning them into data-attribute values using javascript.

For example if the user types in below the following inside the WSIWYG

```
<span>Telephone: +123456</span>
```

It will then be parsed into

```
<span data-info="Telephone">+123456</span>
```

Comment: What you had tried so far ??

Comment: does the user writes the "<span>" and "</span>" too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
var str='<span>Telephone: +123456</span>';
str=str.split(':');
var attrName=str[0].substring(str[0].indexOf('>')+1);
var attrValue=str[1].substring(0,str[1].indexOf('<'));
var element=document.createElement(str[0].substring(1,str[0].indexOf('>')));

element.innerHTML=attrValue;
element.setAttribute('data-info',attrName);
```

Comment: this approach can fail if the user doesnt type `:`

Comment: Yes @ÖzgürErsil you are right . we assume user type in that structure